# Close button in an overlay is visible on page load, and I can't figure out how to hide it

Tags: jquery, css, overlay

I am using this code to load external HTML files into an overlay:

```
<div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">
<div class="contentWrap"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {

    $("a[rel]").overlay({

        mask: 'gray',
        effect: 'apple',

        onBeforeLoad: function() {

            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));

        }
    });
});
```

To add an X in a circle as the close button, I used this CSS:

```
 #overlay .close {
    float:right!important;
    padding:3px 6px!important;
    display:block;
    background:#000!important;
    right:14px!important;
    position:absolute!important;
    color:#fff!important;
    font-family:arial!important;
    font-weight:bold!important;
    margin:6px 6px!important;
    opacity:.65!important;
    filter:initial!important;
    text-shadow:initial;
    border-radius:12px!important;
    font-size:18px!important;
 }
```

It displays perfectly, and when I click on it, the overlay closes, and all is fine. The problem is, when the page originally loads, the X in the circle is already visible. After I open and close a link that opens in the overlay, it doesn't display. But at that initial page load, there it is, at the bottom of the page.

How can I make its initial state hidden? I suspect its' hidden in the jquery.tools.min.js code, possibly one of the spots that refer to "a.tools.overlay", but all that code is so opaque I know I'll just screw it up if I change it.

Can anybody tell me the obvious and much simpler method I *didn't* do? Thanks!

Comment: The full source is [here, for reference.](https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/blob/master/src/overlay/overlay.js)

Comment: you have so many !important's !? these might bite you later if you're not careful. I'd consider (I'm sure you've considered) css 'display: none' and then 'display:block' later as and when you need it.

Comment: Marie, sorry for the long delay... Yes, I put those "!importants" in there as an attempt to rule out inherited properties causing the problem. Most of them will probably be removed later.

I did try using "display:none" and "display:block" but then the close X never shows at all.

I will see if I can glean anything from that source you are linking to, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally just did the obvious and added a function to the A tag that loads the external documents:

```
<a href="anExternal.html" onclick="showX();" rel="#overlay" style="text-decoration:none;">
```

Then showX() is simply:

```
function showX() {
    $("#overlay .close").css("display", "block");
}
```

This allows me to set the initial CSS for .close to display:none and now it works fine.